# SQL Trigger Execute AS CALLER AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE AS EXTERNAL

Tags: sql-server

Could you please explain below stored procedure how it works..

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trg_SQLcm_Department] ON [dbo].[Department] 
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER AFTER  INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [Trg_SQLcm_dbo_Department].[CLRTriggers].[DMLTrigger]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a CLR code, using some specified patterns SQL developers can use VB.NET or C# codes to create database objects like procedures, [CLR UDFs](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-tools/split-2d-array-with-sql-clr-function.aspx), etc.

So to understand what does this trigger do, you should get the source codes or reverse-engineer your binary assembly file code

You can details of such CLR objects in your database using following query

```
SELECT * FROM sys.assemblies
```

Check folder for the CLR assembly by fetching the target folder using following system view

```
select * from sys.assembly_files
```